# Lost luggage, no tag receipts

Tags: luggage, lost-luggage

How do I convince Swissport (at Boston Logan airport) to let me look for my lost bags? (Swissport handles baggage at Boston).

I checked in 3 bags for a multi-hop flight to Boston from Europe using different airlines (SPU > FCO > LIS > BOS, on OU then TAP if you must have details).

My connection FCO > LIS was cancelled by TAP, I was rebooked onto FCO > BOS on Delta.

A TAP agent at FCO removed the tag receipts from my passport (don't know why - I didn't notice till I got to Boston).

Without the tag numbers Delta says they have no way to track my bags.

I suspect the bags are already in Boston (with Swissport, who runs international baggage services at BOS), since they were tagged for BOS a week ago, but Swissport refuses to let me look at the bags they have unless I have the tag numbers. (The bags do have luggage tags with my name and work address.)

What can I do to get the bags? It has been a week now.

Comment: I don't have anything helpful for you, for which I apologise, but as someone who travels in and out of Boston a lot, it's really useful to hear about this.  In future I shall make a habit of taking a smartphone shot of my checked baggage receipts at check-in, so I have an independent record.

Comment: Just to update - it all showed up about 3 weeks later. I will always take photos of tag numbers AND put an Apple AirTag or similar in my luggage, going forward. (I suspect Swissport had them all along...)

Answer (score 9):

You originally deposited your checked luggage at SPU with the air carrier for the first-leg flight. Because that carrier tagged the bags, that carrier should have the tag numbers in their computer system.

Comment: I thought so too. They (Croatia Airlines) say after 72 hours they wipe the computers (but save in "archives"). In a few weeks, maybe, they can retrieve. If they're not too busy.

Comment: The other airlines involved should have the information as well. The agent in FCO probably took the tags to reroute the bags, at which point the information was entered in their systems. It’s probably in the PNR anyway. But did you not file a claim immediately when you arrived and your bags weren’t there?

Comment: @jcaron I did file a claim with Delta on arrival in Boston. They gave me a claim number, but it's totally meaningless as neither they nor I have the tag numbers.